How can I uninstall tracker and still have a files menu icon?
Ubuntu 24. tracker-miner-f is taking 99-100% CPU.  Tried various cures and ended up uninstalling tracker but my files menu icon disappeared. A little research indicated that the files menu is provided by a program called nautilus. Found a link re how to install Nautilus and my files menu returned as did tracker takeing up 99-100% of CPU. How can I get rid of tracker and still have a files menu? Please!

Tracker can't be uninstalled without breaking your system. It's baked-in to the OS. You can disable tracker partially. SEE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694065/how-to-really-completely-disable-gnome-tracker  or   https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-completely-disable-tracker.html  -- Installing 18.04.6 LTS with Ubuntu Pro support works best. 18.04 does NOT have Tracker installed.

You can disable tracker-miner by running sudo systemctl stop tracker-miner-fs-3.service && sudo systemctl disable tracker-miner-fs-3.service I am using Ubuntu 24.04, but the commands to disable tracker-miner in other releases are similar.

On ubuntu 24 none of these work
